# dynamic drop down menu get the wrong value, when calling onchange function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a dynamic dropdown menu on my wordpress site and I want to apply google analytic code so I can track when user click on any of the option and show the name of the value (not the id!). But now when I call the function using onchange, It will pass me the last value name from last dropdown menu. The `<?php echo $value['value_name'] ?>` can give me the right name and create the menu for me, but when I use the same code inside of the onchange function, the correct value didn't pass to the function! I don't quite get why I got such result and no clue about the solution. Thank you for advance of any kind of help and answer.

Here is the PHP code:

```
   <?php if ( isset( $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['view_filtre']       ) &&  $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['view_filtre'] == 'selected' ):?>
     <li>
       <!-- Problem Here  -->
       <select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call('<?php echo $value[value_name]?>')">
         <?php if (  isset( $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['all_field_enable'] ) &&  $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['all_field_enable'] == 'yes'  ):?>
           <option value="all">
              <?php echo ( empty ( $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['all_field_label'] ) )?'All':$optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['all_field_label'];?>                                                         
           </option>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;

    foreach( (array)$group['value'] as $value  ):
    // generate catgory filter link

    $param['filter'] = $value['filter_value_id'];

    if ( isset( $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['view_filtre'] ) &&  $optin_filter_manager[ $group['filter_id'] ]['view_filtre'] == 'selected' ):?>
        <option name="<?php echo $value['value_name'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value['filter_value_id']?>" <?php selected( in_array( $value['filter_value_id'], (array) $filters ) ); ?> 
        <!-- get variable's name -->
        <?php echo $value['value_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php else:?>
```

Here is my Javascript code for google analytics call:

```
function ga_call(value){
    ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'Filter',value);
}
```

======================================================

This is the follow up of the question. Thank you for caspian's answer and here is my modified code:

```
<select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is server side - javascript is client side. When a browser goes to the page, it will render

```
<select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call('<?php echo $value[value_name]?>')">
```

as

```
<select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call('current_value')">
```

Get the current value of the dropdown:

```
<select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call(this.value)">
```

Get the text of the selected item of a dropdown

```
<select name="filter_value[<?php echo $group['filter_id']?>]" onchange="ga_call(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
```

js fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/WctY2/2/

Comment: Thanks for answering but if I change it as this.value, it will pass the value id instead of the value name and this is not what I want. This is also the reason I use the php code inside of onchange call to display the value's name. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize that there was a difference with the text and value of the items. I've updated the answer to have an option to get the text of the selected value. I would probably change this around to pass this to the function and use some error checking to make sure everything is there before accessing indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I want! The code from js fiddle made it so easy to understand. Thanks!